# performance improvements for cube root in Eigen

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I did profile my code using Valgrind (using the "release with debug information" build) and found out that a significant amount of time (~25%) is spent on one line where I calculate the element-wise cubic root of a big matrix.
Now, I would like to accelerate this step if possible.

Currently, I'm simply using `.pow( 1.0 / 3.0)`. I wonder if there is a way to improve this, maybe by using `std::cbrt()`? But how do I pass this function to Eigen in order to do an element-wise cubic root?

```
#include "iostream"
#include "eigen-3.3.7/Eigen/Dense"

using namespace Eigen;
int main() {
  // generate some random numbers
  VectorXd v = VectorXd::Random(10).array().abs() ;
  std::cout << v << std::endl << std::endl ;

  // calculate the cubic root
  VectorXd s = v.array().pow( 1.0 / 3.0 );
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can use `DenseBase::unaryExpr` but be careful: The fact that `std::cbrt` won't be vectorized could cause quite serious regression and the final performance could be worse.

Comment: @dtell thanks, I'll try it out and see if it improves things. Is there any other way to accelerate this step?

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use it properly?

Comment: Yep, I just tested and benchmarked it. It is faster than pow. I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I also got it working and did a first benchmark. It is ~50% faster. I'll wait for your answer, maybe you got even more improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DenseBase::unaryExpr` and a C++ lambda:

```
VectorXd s = v.unaryExpr([](double coeff){ return std::cbrt(coeff); });
```

A small benchmark using [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

using namespace Eigen;

static void BM_Pow(benchmark::State& state)
{
  VectorXd v = VectorXd::Random(state.range(0)).array().abs();
  VectorXd s;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(s = v.array().pow( 1.0 / 3.0 ));
    benchmark::ClobberMemory();
  }
}

static void BM_Cbrt(benchmark::State& state)
{
  VectorXd v = VectorXd::Random(state.range(0)).array().abs();
  VectorXd s;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(s = v.unaryExpr([](double coeff){ return std::cbrt(coeff); }));
    benchmark::ClobberMemory();
  }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_Pow) -> Range(4, 10000);
BENCHMARK(BM_Cbrt) -> Range(4, 10000);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Compiling with `-O3` gives the following on my machine:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time           CPU Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
BM_Pow/4              69 ns         69 ns   10099698
BM_Pow/8             134 ns        134 ns    5391874
BM_Pow/64           1043 ns       1043 ns     673401
BM_Pow/512          8476 ns       8474 ns      82371
BM_Pow/4096        68708 ns      68702 ns      10839
BM_Pow/10000      160833 ns     160566 ns       4222
BM_Cbrt/4             23 ns         23 ns   31538209
BM_Cbrt/8             45 ns         45 ns   15129345
BM_Cbrt/64           358 ns        358 ns    1968338
BM_Cbrt/512         2810 ns       2809 ns     254678
BM_Cbrt/4096       23926 ns      23855 ns      31430
BM_Cbrt/10000      55692 ns      55568 ns      12765
```

so this seems to be worth.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you move the division `1.0/3.0` outside of the loop into a const?

Comment: Absolutely not. A simple pattern like `1.0/3.0` will be evaluated at compile-time even for less aggressive opt. levels.

Comment: I was wondering whether putting it inside the `DoNotOptimise` macro would change that, but I think it only affects the results and not the rest of the expression, so should be ok here.

Comment: Ah, I see. Despite the name `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` doesn't prevent optimisations but forces a write to either a register or memory.